# How to check, read and create binary C files

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to make a program that when it is started it checks if already entered data is loaded if not it asks for struct data, saves and continues the program;

```
#define MAX_ESCOLA 5

typedef struct{
    int identificardor;
    char nome_escola[30];
    char localidade_escola[20];
}t_inserir_escola;

int main()
{
    int numero_questionario = 0;

    t_inserir_escola vetor_adicionar_escola[MAX_ESCOLA];
 
    if(?)
    {
        registar_escolas(vetor_adicionar_escola);
        safe(vetor_adicionar_escola);
    }else
        printf("\n|dados já inseridos|");

    //t_inquerido vetor_inqueridos[MAX_QUESTIONARIO];
    //menu(vetor_inqueridos, numero_questionario, vetor_adicionar_escola, vetor_adicionar_escola);
}

void safe(t_inserir_escola vetor_adicionar_escola[])
{
?
}

void read(t_inserir_escola vetor_adicionar_escola[])
{
?
}
```

This is the first time I’m working on files if anyone can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: You just open a file for writing with the binary flag enabled. Dump your data out that way, then read it back in much the same.

Comment: Consider using [JSON](http://json.org/) or [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/). Binary files without precautions are not portable!